# "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP" when calling dll function

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have a dll with lib.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef EXPORTS
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" API void test1(std::vector<ValueType*>* functions);
```

and lib.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "ValueType.h"
#include "NumberValue.h"

#include "TestLib.h"

void test1(std::vector<ValueType*>* functions) {
    functions->push_back(new NumberValue(123321));
```

And main file, that uses this dll is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>


#include "ValueType.h"


using namespace std;


typedef void (WINAPI* importedInitFunction)(std::vector<ValueType*>*);
importedInitFunction test1F;

std::vector<ValueType*> values;


int main() {
    while (1) {
        HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("DllTest1.dll");


        test1F = (importedInitFunction)GetProcAddress(lib, "test1");

        test1F(&values);
        test1F(&values);

        std::cout << values.at(0)->asString();

        FreeLibrary(lib);
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i'm trying to compile my code, i catch error that says: "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.", on line "test1F(&values);".

How to fix it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there's almost *never* any reason to have pointers to containers.

Comment: WINAPI in the function pointer declaration is wrong, this is a `__cdecl` function.  The stack gets imbalanced because the target function doesn't pop the arguments off the stack.  Fwiw, favor the /DELAYLOAD linker option before LoadLibrary(), less risky and avoids extern "C" on a function that isn't C.

Comment: for what you use LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress instead use import library ?

Comment: Why this question has upvote? This is bazillion question about RTC failure 0 and almost always answer is bad calling conention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the main program you declare the function pointer `WINAPI` which expands to [`__stdcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019), but the default calling convention (which is used by the DLL) is [`__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019).

This mismatch in calling conventions is what is causing your problems. To solve it, remove the `WINAPI` macro, or make the DLL function *also* `WINAPI`.